# Workaround for Jest to use Visual Studio npm Task Runner

Tags: visual-studio, jestjs, task-runner-explorer

I'm currently trying to set up Jest for a Visual Studio project and I want to use Visual Studio's npm Task Runner to run an `npm test` script. When I run the test through the task runner, I get this error:

```
internal/process/stdio.js:82
    throw new Error('Implement me. Unknown stdin file type!');
    ^
Error: Implement me. Unknown stdin file type!
    at process.getStdin [as stdin] (internal/process/stdio.js:82:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\jest_test\jest_test\node_modules\jest-cli\build\reporters\DefaultReporter.js:32:30)
```

I realized that the problem is that the task runner is read-only, but Jest uses `process.stdin` so I was wondering if there is any way to work around this problem for Visual Studio to use Jest.

(The script has no problem running through the command line.)

Comment: Have you tried the jest plugin for VS Code: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Orta.vscode-jest

Comment: I am having the same issue. I know this is almost a year old post, but if anyone got any answers/updates/thoughts on this - that would be great!